# Powerline fonts not working with vim on archlinux

Tags: vim, archlinux, powerline, vim-powerline

I get bad symbols  in places

```
$ pacman -Qqe | grep powerline                                
powerline
powerline-fonts
powerline-vim

$ pacman -Qqe | grep vim-airline                              
vim-airline
vim-airline-themes

$ python --version                                         
Python 3.6.4

$ python -m pip list | grep powerline                          
powerline-status (2.6)

$ python2 -m pip list | grep powerline                         
powerline-status (2.6)

$ cat .vimrc | grep powerline                                 
Plug 'powerline/powerline-fonts'
let g:powerline_pycmd="py"
let g:airline_powerline_fonts=1

$ cat .vimrc | grep -n font                                    
7:Plug 'powerline/powerline-fonts'
82:set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline:h14
88:let g:airline_powerline_fonts=1
```

I have tried everything, installed from repo. to download pre-compiled packages. But nothing works.

Terminal: iterm2, it works on client but when sshing into server on the same terminal.